# group by alternate spellings

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have a table of addresses with the expected columns(flat, house, street, postcode, country etc).

I'm using PHP to perform a MySQL search from a form input ($street). I have successfully made it so I can search by all road spelling variations (for example: 'street', 'st', 'st.') as below. I'd like the output array to be grouped by street. The below groups by each individual spelling. Is there a way my return groups can include all variations of the spellings?

**My Code**

```
<?php
    $results = $db->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM entries
        WHERE 
        street = :street
        OR street = REPLACE(:street, 'st', 'street')
        OR street = REPLACE(:street, 'st.', 'street')
        OR street = REPLACE(:street, 'st.', 'st')
        OR street = REPLACE(:street, 'street', 'st')
        OR street = REPLACE(:street, 'street', 'st.')

        GROUP BY street, house
    ")

    $results->bindParam(':street', $street);
    $results->execute();

    $output = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
    return $output;
?>
```

**Current example output**

```
[1] Church Street
    [1] 12 Church Street
    [2] 25 Church Street
[2] Church St.
    [1] 19 Church St.
```

**Desired example output**

```
[1] Church Street
    [1] 12 Church Street
    [2] 25 Church Street
    [3] 19 Church St.
```

Comment: What is the street was called "St. Augustine Street"? It would become "Street Augustine Street."

Comment: Well spotted. This is searching, not entering, so searching for stuff that doesn't exist isn't a problem :)

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, your use of a GROUP BY clause is inappropriate

Comment: @Strawberry I'm a novice, but I didn't think you needed to aggregate before grouping in MySQL?http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: You do, because otherwise you're (potentially) returning meaningless results. There are some very experienced users here who advocate its use in circumstances similar to this - and it has demonstrated tiny performance benefits - but I think it's just too prone to abuse.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the same problem in your data that you are trying to take care of in your `where` clause.  Rectifying addresses can be a challenge.  Here is an attempt for this small example:

```
SELECT *
FROM entries
WHERE street = :street
      OR street = REPLACE(:street, 'st', 'street')
      OR street = REPLACE(:street, 'st.', 'street')
      OR street = REPLACE(:street, 'st.', 'st')
      OR street = REPLACE(:street, 'street', 'st')
      OR street = REPLACE(:street, 'street', 'st.')
GROUP BY (case when street like '%st' then concat(street, 'reet')
               when street like '% st.' then replace(street, ' st.', ' street')
               else street
          end), house;
```

EDIT:

You should be repeating the `group by expression in the`select` clause:

```
SELECT (case when street like '%st' then concat(street, 'reet')
             when street like '% st.' then replace(street, ' st.', ' street')
             else street
        end) as street, house
FROM entries
WHERE street = :street
      OR street = REPLACE(:street, 'st', 'street')
      OR street = REPLACE(:street, 'st.', 'street')
      OR street = REPLACE(:street, 'st.', 'st')
      OR street = REPLACE(:street, 'street', 'st')
      OR street = REPLACE(:street, 'street', 'st.')
GROUP BY (case when street like '%st' then concat(street, 'reet')
               when street like '% st.' then replace(street, ' st.', ' street')
               else street
          end), house;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. The concat works, but the replace line causes an SQL error. I guess a problem with the syntax. I'm a complete newbie, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Got it. It was the additional comma at the end of "then concat(street, 'reet'),"

Comment: OK, so this kinda works. It does group them all together, but it does it for each spelling, so essentially I end up with 2 arrays (Church St. and Church Street), each containing the same 3 records. Are you able to make any suggestion on how to group them as you suggested, but only display them under 'church street'? Thanks in advance.